# Middleman asset_hash with Angular templateUrl

Tags: javascript, ruby, angularjs, middleman

I am using Middleman with the `activate :asset_hash` option in order to compile assets with the hash to force cache invalidation. The problem is that I also load some html templated with Angular templateUrl like this:

```
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',
....
```

but the `dashboard` file gets compiled with an hash like `templates/dashboard-cc1554f0.html` and so Angular doesn't find the file.

Is there a way to pass within the Angular file the same hash that Middleman generates on build ?

Answer (score 0):

I must tell you that I didn't meet this problem (All my js, css and images are hashed, but html files are not). Here is my Gemfile

**Gemfile**

```
# If you do not have OpenSSL installed, update
# the following line to use "http://" instead
source 'https://ruby.taobao.org'

gem "middleman", "~>4.0.0"

# Live-reloading plugin
# gem "middleman-livereload", "~> 3.2.0"

# For faster file watcher updates on Windows:
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.0", :platforms => [:mswin, :mingw]

# Windows does not come with time zone data
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mswin, :mingw, :jruby]

gem "middleman-minify-html"

gem "middleman-sprockets", "~> 4.0.0.rc"
```

And here is my `config.rb`

**config.rb**

```
set :css_dir, 'css'

set :js_dir, 'app'

set :images_dir, 'images'

set :layout, false

# Build-specific configuration
configure :development do
  set :backend, 'http://localhost:3000'
  set :frontend, 'http://localhost:4567/#'
end

configure :build do
  set :backend, 'https://api.example.com'
  set :frontend, 'https://www.example.com/#'

  # For example, change the Compass output style for deployment
  activate :minify_css

  # Minify Javascript on build
  activate :minify_javascript

  # Minify HTML files on build, requires gem `middleman-minify-html`
  activate :minify_html

  # Enable cache buster
  activate :asset_hash

  # gzip text files
  activate :gzip
end
```

You can see that I use Middleman 4.0.

If your problem remains after upgrading middleman, maybe you can rename your js file to `xxx.js.erb` and try the helper `url_for`.

Comment: I've tried `url_for` like this:

    `when('/dashboard', {
                templateUrl: '<%= url_for("templates/dashboard.html") %>'`

but it didn't take into account the asset hash